# 2 virtualhosts in XAMPP Apache - only one site works

Tags: xampp

I made 2 virtualhosts in XAMPP Apache environment in in httpd.conf
Only first one works. Second one resolves to first entry.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\shop1"
    ServerName shop1
    ServerAlias shop1
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm not-a-file
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm not-a-file
</VirtualHost>
```

If I switch entries I get same results only other site is shown.
In hosts table, I have both

127.0.0.1         localhost
127.0.0.1         shop1

Each time, I change  httpd.conf, I restart apache server.
Cleared browser cache each time.

Comment: The first virtual host is the fallback (default). You might want to check what your browser actually sends in the `Host` header field. It’s probably not just “shop1”. An easy way to check this would be your browser’s integrated debugging tool or an external program like Fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the ip address of multiple vhosts will be served on with NameVirtualHost directive.

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1
```

Here is the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
NameVirtualHost *
    <VirtualHost *>
        DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
        ServerName localhost
    </VirtualHost>
    <VirtualHost *>
        DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\shop1"
        ServerName shop1
        <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\shop1">
            DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm not-a-file
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```